# Slaptest for slapd.conf fails due to an invalid path

Tags: ldap, openldap, ubuntu-12.04

I have just installed Openldap on Xubuntu. The slapd daemon is working and I can easily stop and start it. Nevertheless when I run a test for the configuration file slapd.conf as follows:

slapdtest -v -f /etc/ldap/slapd.conf

I get the following error:

```
5166a149 /etc/ldap/slapd.conf: line 67: invalid path: Permission denied
slaptest: bad configuration file!
```

/etc/ldap/slapd.conf: line 67 is:

```
directory          "var/lib/ldap"
```

I don't know if there is a probmlem with the files access rights in that directory because it keeps saying that the path is invalid:

```
reza@testserver:/etc/ldap$ ls -l /var/lib/ldap/*
-rw-r--r-- 1 openldap openldap     2048 Apr 11 11:15 /var/lib/ldap/alock
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap    24576 Apr 11 11:15 /var/lib/ldap/__db.001
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap   344064 Apr 11 13:45 /var/lib/ldap/__db.002
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap  2629632 Apr 11 11:15 /var/lib/ldap/__db.003
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap   163840 Apr 11 11:45 /var/lib/ldap/__db.004
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap   909312 Apr 11 11:15 /var/lib/ldap/__db.005
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap    32768 Apr 11 11:45 /var/lib/ldap/__db.006
-rw-r--r-- 1 openldap openldap       96 Apr 10 17:14 /var/lib/ldap/DB_CONFIG
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap     8192 Apr 10 17:14 /var/lib/ldap/dn2id.bdb
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap    32768 Apr 10 17:14 /var/lib/ldap/id2entry.bdb
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap 10485760 Apr 11 11:45 /var/lib/ldap/log.0000000001
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap     8192 Apr 10 17:14 /var/lib/ldap/objectClass.bdb
```

The server is XUbuntu 12.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the first slash in the directory name:

```
directory          "var/lib/ldap"
```

should be

```
directory          "/var/lib/ldap"
```